# Windows Installer with Administrator rights

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, administrator

I use Wix toolset 3.5 and am interested to know if there is any windows installer which installs only for the administrator?

Comment: You can't install an application only to Administrators. You have really two options, no matter what install technology you use: *per-user* (install to the currently logged in user only) or *per-machine* (install for *all* users of the computer).

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one user with administrative privileges, so I would install for all users and set up the application to require admin rights at start-up. One way to do that is with an application manifest: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Thank you i think it solved most of my problems however it seems like an installer created with Wix toolset asks for an admin password , you talked about requiring admin rights at start up ,

Comment: @EmmaRochweel If UAC is enabled, Vista+ will ask for administrator credentials, if the current user is not a member of Administrators group; it simply shows elevation confirmation if the user is in Administrators group. I believe this is what you want: such behavior is consistent with other application, and it ensures only administrators can run the app. If UAC is disabled or in XP, app will launch in either case: user is admin or not; therefore your app should handle this situation and show appropriate error message.

Answer (score 1):

MOreover, in addition to the answer of @Wim and comments, u can try to create a logic of ur installer based on WiX flag `Privileged`. it will help u to install some features (or even components) only for admin user (this flag check if the current user has admin rights). Usage of this flag is just simple:

```
 <Component Id="" Guid="">Priveleged</Component>
```

and in this case component will install only when the current user has an admin rights. hope will help